# How to use google commands shortcuts to click elements on active webpage?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am try to create a google extension which will allow me to click on buttons, based on id, with the help of google commands.

I can only find examples of using google commands with the background scripts which does not give me access to the actualy web page on the active tab. The key thing I want to achieve is this:

press Ctrl+Shift+0 and click a button based document query.

I have also thought of injecting content scripts, but that does not let me use the google command api to get shortcuts.

Comment: You need to use two scripts: the background script to use chrome.commands API and a content script to access the web pages. More info: [architecture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch).

Comment: How would I then call a function in the content script ? I can see that I have to send some a message with sendMessage. But in the "onMessage" method in the content script which I have injected declaratively it does not work. There is no connection to established.

Comment: Unfortunately it's impossible to help without seeing [MCVE](/help/mcve).